# Append new value to option select last value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to append new value at the end of a option select box. The number should continue instead of starting from 1.

```js
var n_standard = 1;

function removeStandard() {
  var select = document.getElementById('selectBoxStandard');
  for (var i = Number($("#selectBoxStandard").val()); i <= n_standard; i++){
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = i;
    opt.innerHTML = i;
    select.appendChild(opt);
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="rooms" style="color:black">No. of rooms: </label>
<select required tabindex="10" id="selectBoxStandard" name="n_rooms">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
```

This javascript code will fill the value of option based on the value of **n_standard** it should continue the number instead of starting from 1 again.

**Program output**

```
   option
    0
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    1
```

**Expected output**

```
option
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve. What is removeStandard function and when it gets called.?

Comment: Some confusion.  What's `n_standard` and how is it set?  Why does your `for` loop *start* at the `select` value rather than `n_standard`?

Comment: why dont you append with document.getElementById("selectBoxStandard").length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query how many `option`s the `select` currently has and add that as an offset:

```
var offset = select.find("option").length;
opt.value = i + offset;
```

```js
var n_standard = 1;

function removeStandard() {
  var select = $('#selectBoxStandard');
  var offset = select.find("option").length;

  // not clear why you would start at 5 and check 5<=1 which will always give nothing
  // so for demo, always adds one item (so doesn't need the loop)
  // change n_standard to add more than one at a time
  //for (var i = Number(select.val()); i <= n_standard; i++) {

  for (var i = 0; i < n_standard; ++i) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = i + offset;
    opt.innerHTML = i + offset;
    select.get(0).appendChild(opt);
  }
}

$("#b").click(removeStandard);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="rooms" style="color:black">No. of rooms: </label>
<select required tabindex="10" id="selectBoxStandard" name="n_rooms">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>

</select>
<button id='b'>click me</button>
```

Alternatively, you could set the start value to the highest value if there might be gaps.

Answer (score 1):

Use `select.length` in your code to get the number of `<option>` in `<select>`. 
 https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_length.asp

```
var n_standard = 1;
function removeStandard(){
 var select = document.getElementById('selectBoxStandard');
  for (var i = Number($("#selectBoxStandard").val()); i< n_standard; i++){
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = select.length;
    opt.innerHTML = select.length;
    select.appendChild(opt);
  }
}

removeStandard();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to do. But If you are trying to increase the option through that for loop try this:

```
var n_standard = 9;
var select = document.getElementById('selectBoxStandard');
for (var i = Number(select.value); i <= n_standard; i++) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = i;
            opt.innerHTML = i;
            select.appendChild(opt);}
```

This will dynamically add options with value increased based on **n_standar**.